# GL_INVALID_OPERATION when uploading compressed textures

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, texture2d

I am getting an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` every time I try to upload a `DXT1` texture with several mipmap levels using Qt `QOpenGLTexture`. For mipmap level 0 everything is ok, but for any other I get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` at `glCompressedTexSubImage2DEXT()` inside Qt library. Where is my mistake?

Code:

```
QOpenGLVertexArrayObject::Binder vaoBinder(&mVAO);
bindProgram();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

const dds::Image *base = parser.getImageData(0);

mTexture.setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGB_DXT1);
mTexture.setSize(base->width, base->height);
mTexture.setMipLevelRange(0, parser.getMipmapCount());
mTexture.allocateStorage();
mTexture.bind();

for (size_t i = 0; i < parser.getMipmapCount(); i++)
{
    // Image data represents a single mipmap level of a texture.
    const dds::Image *img = parser.getImageData(i);

    mTexture.setCompressedData(i, img->dataSize, img->data);
    qDebug() << "size: " << img->width << img->height;
    qDebug() << "i: " << i << " error: " << glGetError();
}

mTexture.setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
mProgram.setUniformValue("objectTexture", 0);

unbindProgram();
```

Here is program log:

```
size:  2048 2048
i:  0  error:  0
size:  1024 1024
i:  1  error:  1282
size:  512 512
i:  2  error:  1282
size:  256 256
i:  3  error:  1282
...
size:  1 1
i:  11  error:  1282
```

Here is part of glIntercept log:

```
glGenTextures(1,00000000006DCE68)
glTextureParameteriEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL,0)
glTextureParameteriEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL,11)
glTextureStorage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,2048,2048)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1)
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,2048,2048,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,2097152,00000000147A0080)
glGetError()=GL_NO_ERROR 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,0,0,1024,1024,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,524288,00000000149A0080) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,2,0,0,512,512,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,131072,0000000014A20080) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,3,0,0,256,256,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,32768,0000000014A40080) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,4,0,0,128,128,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,8192,0000000014A48080) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,5,0,0,64,64,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,2048,0000000014A4A080) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,6,0,0,32,32,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,512,0000000014A4A880) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,7,0,0,16,16,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,128,0000000014A4AA80) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,8,0,0,8,8,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,32,0000000014A4AB00) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,9,0,0,4,4,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,8,0000000014A4AB20) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,10,0,0,2,2,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,8,0000000014A4AB28) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glCompressedTextureSubImage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,11,0,0,1,1,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,8,0000000014A4AB30) glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glGetError()=GL_INVALID_OPERATION 
glTextureParameteriEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,9729)
glTextureParameteriEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,9729)
```

Comment: From looking at the Qt documentation, I think you might need to call `setMipLevels()` instead of `setMipLevelRange()`. The former specifies how many levels you want to allocate, while the latter specifies the range for sampling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only allocating enough memory for a single mipmap when you call `glTextureStorage2DEXT`. The third argument is the number of mipmap levels you want to allocate - in your case, this should be 11:

```
glTextureStorage2DEXT(1,GL_TEXTURE_2D,11,GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT,2048,2048)
```

For a given width and height, you can calculate the number of levels that will be needed to generate a full mipmap chain with `floor(log2(max(width, height))) + 1`.

---

Sorry, I didn't quite answer the question! Instead of calling `setMipLevelRange`, you should be calling [`setMipLevels`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#setMipLevels). As stated in the Qt documentation for `setMipLevels`:

> For texture targets that support mipmaps, this function sets the requested number of mipmap levels to allocate storage for. This function should be called before storage is allocated for the texture.

This should work:

```
mTexture.setMipLevels(floor(log2(max(width, height))) + 1);
```

Or using your `parser.getMipmapCount()` method:

```
mTexture.setMipLevels(parser.getMipmapCount());
```